# WordPress WooCommerce mails are blocked

Tags: wordpress, email, smtp

I have an issue with the Wordpress Plugin WooCommerce. There are some automatically sent mails going out the system.

Some of the recipients don't get the mails. I think that the mails are sent but blocked by the provider they are using.

Do anybody have some experinces with that issue? Is there any log I can search for errors or warnings?

Thanks
be

I have already contacted the support of VideoWhisper but haven't got any feedback since yet. And I have already tried a SMTP plugin.

Comment: This is more likely related to your hosting provider, you might need to add some DNS records.

Comment: DNS records are set, maybe the provider is blocked by gmx or something